# Create and Register a COM Server Object .NET

Tags: c#, com

I've been following a set of tutorials ([like this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7859/Building-COM-Objects-in-C)) to create a simple COM server object.

Say I've got a simple hello world:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("392930B3-9CD0-4247-8C69-83168D1C8F77")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("nathanr.HellowWorldCom")]
class HelloWorldCom : IHelloWorldCom
{
    public int HelloWorld()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

With just as simple an interface:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("C08205BE-1393-4070-AE57-FA47F0D653C3")]
interface IHelloWorldCom
{
    [DispId(1)]
    int HelloWorld();
}
```

And of course, can't forget the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file:

```
...
[assembly: ComVisible(true)]
[assembly: AssemblyKeyFile("HelloWorldCOM.snk")]
...
```

The problem is when I build the `HelloWorldCom.dll` and try to register it, `regasm` just sticks its tongue out at me:

```
RegAsm : warning RA00000 : No types were registered.
```

And just to cover my bases I cracked open `Regedit` and did a search for the `ProgID`.  It wasn't there, which honestly wasn't a surprise.

**Am I missing something obvious?**

This whole test project is part of a larger (actually useful) set up which is also failing to register.

Comment: you're missing "public" from the class definition. It's going to be internal by default ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will be a very long answer: add *public*

```
 public class HelloWorldCom : IHelloWorldCom
```

Comment: /facepalm.  Yes this fixes the problem.  In my hurry to strip down my earlier issue with COM I missed the public.  I'll mark this as the accepted answer, because, yes it certainly does register.  But now I'm back to my earlier issue of not being able to create the client object.

Answer (score 0):

There might be couple of issues:

1. You are selecting an incorrect .net framework. In my case, I was trying to register the dll with 2.0 framework, as opposed to 64 bit 4.0 framework
2. Your DLL is not publicly exposed.

Hope that resolves your issue.

Cheers